# Return a record if no other similar record exists

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.5

i have a question to ask,
it is related to mariadb sql language >10.4.

I have this database with these fields and these values entered

| ir_f | id_r | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | linea 1 |
| 1 | 0 | linea 2 |
| 1 | 0 | linea 3 |
| 2 | 0 | linea 15 |
| 2 | 0 | linea 16 |
| 2 | 17 | linea 16 modified |
| 2 | 0 | linea 17 |
| 2 | 0 | linea 18 |

I think to describe what I need it is better to report
the 2 tables I would need to get.

If I use "select * from database where id_f = 1 and id_r = 0" it returns me these values

| ir_f | id_r | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | linea 1 |
| 1 | 0 | linea 2 |
| 1 | 0 | linea 3 |

but how do I write the select to make it return
id_f = 2 and (id_r = 0 or id_r = 17) but not returning the row with id_r = 0 if the row with id_r = 17 exists?

| ir_f | id_r | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | linea 15 |
| 2 | 17 | linea 16 modified |
| 2 | 0 | linea 17 |
| 2 | 0 | linea 18 |

To explain a little better. id_r is the reference to the restaurants, id_f is the reference to the franchise.

This db is used to create your own custom web page.

id_r = 0 means it applies to all restaurants, id_r > 0 means that record applies to that single restaurant .

So if the row contains a number greater than 0 it must be returned instead of the one that contains 0.

I don't know if I explained it better or if I messed it up even more

I hope this time I was clearer ... but I don't know how to explain myself better ... if you look at the tables I think you can see what I would like to achieve

I can also add an additional field if needed

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Better if you can create a https://dbfiddle.uk/ that includes the query that you've tried, along with all related table data/examples.

Answer (score 0):

Use an inner query to select the `max` value and join back to the same table to get the results:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tbl a
JOIN ( SELECT ir_f, MAX(id_r) as id_r FROM tbl WHERE ir_f = :restaurant: GROUP BY ir_f) m
  USING (ir_f, id_r)
```